# unexpected token: ON in hql query when using left outer join

Tags: hibernate, left-join, hql

I am using left join in hibernate but it throws me an exception i.e. is Unexpected token "ON"
my query work in sql well but i want to use the same query in hql. So please help me to overcome from this exception.

```
String hql = "SELECT p.posSerialNo, p.posAssignDate,p.posDetails,p.posMake,p.posSoftwareVer,p.merchants ,m.merchantFirstname, m.merchantLastname , m.merchantBusinessName FROM PosDevices as p LEFT JOIN Merchants as m ON p.merchants = m.merchantId";

            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            System.out.println(query);
            posList1 = query.list();
```

Comment: your syntax is wrong. `HQL` syntax is exact not same as normal `SQL`. Check it on Google :)

Comment: I know there is syntax difference between hql and sql but i didnt get proepr solution from there rhats y I posted here .

Comment: see, my answer. This may will help you.

Answer (score 2):

`Hibernate` will take care of your mappings (`Primary key` of parent and `FK` in child)

For your understanding,

**HQL Used**

```
select from Parent as p left outer join p.child  as c
```

**Generated SQL**

```
select parent0_.id as id2_0_, child1_.id as id0_1_, parent0_.childFK as childFK2_0_, parent0_.prop as prop2_0_, child1_.childProp as childProp0_1_ from Parent parent0_ left outer join Child child1_ on parent0_.childFK=child1_.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [hql official document](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins).

```
String hql = "SELECT p.posSerialNo, p.posAssignDate,p.posDetails,p.posMake,p.posSoftwareVer,p.merchants ,m.merchantFirstname, m.merchantLastname , m.merchantBusinessName FROM PosDevices as p LEFT OUTER JOIN Merchants as m";
```

Try this

Comment: no its not working here how i can compare primary key and foreign key relationship

Comment: what error are you getting? Hibernate will compare your primary key and foreign key relationship for you. It will check from your annotation or xml file.